# Metamask: transaction decoding is not available at chain id 97

Tags: blockchain, metamask

this are the error i am facing my project is based on degree verification using blockchain when i submit a document metamask popup for transaction for its gas fees butwhen confirm the transaction goes in to pending when try to speed up transaction after that no speed up no cancellation popup and when copy the transaction id and check into testbscan.com it dont find my transaction why chain id 97 is not working plz solve my issue i shall be very thankful to you all.

my image of error showing: [https://ibb.co/QnqXyTg](https://ibb.co/7KSMpPM)

https://ibb.co/7KSMpPM

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You need to post your code so someone can even start to guess at your problem.